# Embedded jetty rewrite and redirect http to https and path both using RewriteHandler and SecuredRedirectHandler

Tags: java, jetty

I have an embedded jetty application (jetty 9.3.12) that I need to redirect requests from http://host and http://host/my/app to https://host/my/app

I have been using RewriteHandler for a while now to successfully redirect http://host -> http://host/my/app and https://host -> https://host/my/app.

**I can't figure out how to make http://host -> https://host/my/app work.**

I also have another jetty context that the same Server handles which I'll call /other (not reflected in the code below).  I do not want to redirect http://other -> https://other.

Here is a summary of what I want to happen

```
http:// -> https://my/app 
http://my/app -> https://my/app 
https:// -> https://my/app 
http://other -> no change
```

If I add SecuredRedirectHandler directly to the server handlers (see ALTERNATIVE METHOD in code) than I get a 404 Problem accessing /my/app. Reason: Not found.

If I add the SecuredRedirectHandler behind the RewriteHandler then nothing happens (code below).

```
private Server createServer() {
    Server server = new Server();
    configureConnectors(server);
    HandlerCollection handlers = getHandlers(server);

    RewriteHandler rewriteHandler = createRewriteHandler(server);
    server.setHandler(rewriteHandler);

    return server;
}

private void configureConnectors(Server server) {
    List<ServerConnector> connectors = new ArrayList<>();
    ServerConnect httpsConnector = createHttpsConnector(server);
    boolean httpsEnabled = httpsConnector != null;
    ServerConnector httpConnector = createHttpConnector(server, httpsEnabled);
    connectors.add(httpConnector);
    connectors.add(httpsConnector);
    // ALTERNATIVE METHOD - Results in 404 - Problem access /my/app Reason: Not Found
    //addHandlerAsFirst(new SecuredRedirectHandler(), server);

    for (ServerConnector connector : connectors) {
        server.addConnector(connector);
    }
}

private ServerConnector createHttpConnector(Server server, boolean httpsEnabled) {
    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
    if (httpsEnabled) {
        Integer httpsPort = getServiceUrl().getPortSsl();
        httpConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
        httpConfig.setSecureScheme(HttpScheme.HTTPS.asString());
        httpConfig.setSecurePort(httpsPort);
    }

    Integer port = getServiceUrl().getPort();

    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
    connector.setPort(port);
    configureConnector(connector);

    return connector;
}

private ServerConnector createHttpsConnector(Server server) {
    Integer httpsPort = getServiceUrl().getPortSsl();
    Integer port = httpsPort;

    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = null;
    try {
        sslContextFactory = createSslContextFactory();
    } catch (ConfigurationException | NotFoundException e) {
        log.err(m, e, "Create SSL Context failed: Perhaps Certificate Policy Bindings are not configured?");
        return null;
    }

    SslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HTTP_VERSION);

    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, connectionFactory, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
    connector.setPort(port);
    configureConnector(connector);

    return connector;
}

public RewriteHandler createRewriteContext(HandlerCollection handlerCollection) {
    RewriteHandler rewrite = new RewriteHandler();
    rewrite.setRewriteRequestURI(true);
    rewrite.setRewritePathInfo(false);
    rewrite.setOriginalPathAttribute("requestedPath");
    rewrite.setHandler(handlerCollection);

    String path = AppProductConfig.CONSOLE_CONTEXT_ROOT + AppUI.APP_PATH;

    /*
     * Redirect "/" to "/console/app".  We use redirect instead of rewrite
     * because Vaadin needs to access it's widgetset files.  The rewrite requires
     * multiple rules to accomplish this.  The redirect is simpler.
     */
    RedirectPatternRule rootRule = new RedirectPatternRule();
    rootRule.setPattern(""); // Redirect / (root)
    rootRule.setLocation(path);
    rewrite.addRule(rootRule);

    return rewrite;
}
protected void addHandlerAsFirst(Handler handler, Server server) {
    HandlerCollection handlers = handlersMap.get(server);
    if (handlers == null) {
        handlers = new HandlerCollection();
        handlersMap.put(server, handlers);
    }

    handlers.prependHandler(handler);
}
```

SOLVED

I was able to get things to working using this approach: [Jetty 9.2.1 redirect http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991508/jetty-9-2-1-redirect-http-to-https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have 2 redirects, not 1.

```
Server
  HandlerList
    SecuredRedirectHandler
    RewriteHandler
      Rule -> "/" to "/my/app"
    ServletContextHandler or WebAppContext
    DefaultHandler
```

Don't attempt to rewrite the path and ALSO redirect to HTTPS.
Just let each one do its own thing independently.

Think about these scenarios:

- `http://host/my/app` (uses SecuredRedirectHandler only)
- `https://host/`  (uses RewriteHandler only)
- `http://host/` (2 redirects, once for scheme, second for path)

Comment: This approach works for the scenario I originally described (thank you!), but in my push to provide a simple example I left out a critical part.  The jetty server is configured to listen for multiple contexts (e.g. "/my/app" and "/other").  I do not want to redirect http://other to https://other.  Is there some way to filter SecuredRedirectHandler to handle only "http://" or "http://my/app"?

Comment: [SecuredRedirectHandler](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/SecuredRedirectHandler.java) only pays attention to the ServerConnector's HttpConfiguration and redirects with the correct scheme and secure port.  It doesn't modify the host, path, or query for its redirect.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Is there a different approach you can recommend?

Comment: If you have a formal WebApp, aka a `WEB-INF/web.xml`, then use a mapped constraint (by url-pattern) with CONFIDENTIAL transport - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42784830/775715